# Is f(x) = πx, { x ∈ ℚ } a continuous function from R→R?

Tags: real-analysis

The actual problem referred to as the image of the rational numbers being a set of irrationals.
I am unable to wrap my head around the fact that a function maps all rationals selectively to the irrationals, then what does it do to the next real number, that is irrational, in the domain, to keep the function continuous.
And is there even a thing like " the next Irrational ".
Should this function not be a constant function, in order to be continuous.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Every linear function $f(x)=ax$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, independently of the value of $a$. This should make sense because the graph of such a function is a continuous, straight line.

Comment: $x\mapsto \pi x$ maps $0$ to $0$. But e.g. $x\mapsto x+\pi$ assigns irrational to every rational number. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by “$, \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \}$”? Do you mean that $f$ is only defined for $x \in \mathbb{Q}$? But then it's not even a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with, so it is trivially not a *continuous* function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. And why the brackets around “$x \in \mathbb{Q}$”? And does $R$ mean $\mathbb{R}$ here?

Comment: @AlannRosas you're right. Berci gave me the details I was looking for. Thanks

Comment: @Berci exactly. My function doesn't map '0' to an irrational so it's the function you gave that I was looking for. Now, such a function, with a condition that the image of rationals is a subset of irrationals, such a function should be a constant function, right?

Comment: @HansLundmark Sorry for that use of brackets. What I meant from that was that there's a condition given that all rationals have an image in the irrationals. And they asked if such a function would be a constant function or not.

Comment: The function $x\mapsto x+\pi$ is clearly not constant. So the answer to the question wether such a function needs to be constant is no.

Comment: And what does “there's a condition given that all rationals have an image in the irrationals” mean? It's still not clear to me exactly how the function $f$ is defined.

Comment: Exactly @HansLundmark , I think that such a function cannot be defined. I'll write explicitly what the person told me, with whom I was discussing.
There is a continuous function, f : R to R. 
If f (Q) ⊂ R - Q, then will f be a constant function?

Comment: OK, that's a perfectly clear question. Why didn't you ask *that*, then?

Comment: @HansLundmark I guess stupidity warrants no reason. haha.

Answer (score 2):

An irrational number isn't special from an analytic point of view. There are more of them than there are rationals, but an irrational number is qualitatively no different from a rational number, as far as their roles on the number line are concerned: both are some point on the line. The rationals just have particularly nice distances to the point 0, which can be expressed solely in terms of the distance between the two points 0 and 1. That's it, really. But it's no requirement of a continuous function to map points with nice distances to 0 to points which also have nice distances to 0. All a continuous function has to do is mapping points which are close to each other to points which are also close to each other. Your function does that, so it's continuous.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. The function I gave is definitely continuous. I should've mentioned more clearly that the condition here is that rationals map to irrationals. But then the function maps 0 to 0. But anyway, Thanks for the response.

Comment: My answer still applies to that other function, though.

Comment: Ok, I got too excited to see the other function that I forgot to notice that it gave me my answer. Thanks again for pointing that out above.